# Is "Type of "X" is partially unknown" a problem with this library or my own code?

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm using another users package and getting the linting warning when importing it:

```
# Throws: Type of "task" is partially unknown
from invoke.tasks import task
```

Is this an issue with the package's code or is there something I'm expected to do in my code?

[Looking at that package](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/blob/506bf4e020c177a03cf4257a22969bad0845e4ee/invoke/tasks.py#L289):

```
def task(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Callable:
    klass: Type[Task] = kwargs.pop("klass", Task)
    # @task -- no options were (probably) given.
    if len(args) == 1 and callable(args[0]) and not isinstance(args[0], Task):
        return klass(args[0], **kwargs)
    # @task(pre, tasks, here)
    if args:
        if "pre" in kwargs:
            raise TypeError(
                "May not give *args and 'pre' kwarg simultaneously!"
            )
        kwargs["pre"] = args
    
    def inner(body: Callable) -> Task[T]:
        _task = klass(body, **kwargs)
        return _task
    
    # update_wrapper(inner, klass)
    return inner
```

Should they have done something like `-> Callable[Any]:`?

If it is an issue with the package is there anything I can do in my code apart from telling the type checker to ignore that line?

Comment: `Callable` by itself (IIRC) is equivalent to `Callable[Any]` (or more specifically `Callable[..., Any]`. The only difference between `task` as written and `task` with no type hints at all is that you know `task` returns some callable value.

Comment: For example, you could call `task(klass="foo")`, and the assignment to `klass` in the first line would type check, because a value of type `Any` can be assigned to a name that expects (a subclass of) `Task`.

Comment: `klass` should be a fixed keyword-only parameter (`def task(*args, klass=Task, **kwargs): ...`). There might be some way of using `ParamSpec` to ensure that the values passed via `args` and `kwargs` are actually suitable to pass to `klass`, but I'm not going to spend more time reading the original code to figure out if that's true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] is there something I'm expected to do in my code?

You are not expected to do anything; in fact, you can ignore all type errors if you want to. They are just there to make you aware of potential bugs.

> Is this an issue with the package's code [...]? [...] Should they have done something like `-> Callable[Any]:`?

Using a generic type with no argument list [is equivalent to](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#generics) giving it an argument list of `Any` values, so what they do is not necessarily wrong. It's just that your type checker (possibly Pyright, and, if so, even more possibly via Pylance) is being strict. Mypy, for instance, [considers](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=eb6a31bec18b4accc23add5f9099acd9) `Callable` the same as `Callable[..., Any]` as long as the `--strict` flag is not enabled.

Note that `Callable` expects [two type arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#annotating-callable-objects), so you can type hint a function that accepts any number of arguments and can return anything as either `Callable[..., Any]` or just `Callable`, but not `Callable[Any]`.

> If it is an issue with the package is there anything I can do [...]

*Generally*, if you know how to fix a bug, you can and should contribute so that others won't have to face the same situation.

> [...] in my code apart from telling the type checker to ignore that line?

As stated, you don't *have* to, but to avoid type errors you can [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) it to whatever type you want, so that your code can still be type safe.

Personally, I encourage people to type hint their code properly. It is simply better for both the developers and the users of the code, although at times there might be bugs and discrepancies between type checkers which make your burden a bit (or a lot) heavier.

Comment: `you can cast it to whatever type you want` in my import statement? How do I do that? I'm asking if there is something in my code I can do apart from ignoring the warning on that import statement line.

Comment: @red888 Not in the same `import` statement, but [right after that](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBAxmA28CmMAuBLMA7AzgOgEMAjGKdCABzBFSgGEDFjkBYAKFEilQE8L0sAczKVqtGARyoANFBBIAbkkYB9XhSTstbAMRQAKgAt0OMqYBWAVylRrSACbcwUCOXSlUhpFCLKFmSxAoMGARKho8KABJQSxqb3RUPHZ7JFDgAAoASigAWgA%2BekZ4ZiQALnYoKqg8Wu1USQBrKABeKEycqD0AURBwEDKa2qgKAhp0Yp5bLEa4gHcsdnklVXUkDIacRs69DNq8HIKoAFUZ%2BcW2dk3mtokpDIYmImQAbRepEFkBVABdWWB4GACL9ZNcsktFMp4Go%2BOswVVdh8vlhUIdCgCgah6sYcCoTGowA1EDwVMABN42tcMgByYBgMDU2QAZnBbE8%2BJABBMSFxSD61FMlKaGRefyg1KIY2prKAA).

Comment: You can also [use](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMogCmAboQIYA2A%2BvAoQDRQAqAmgAoCiVAwgBIfcA0gEkAcgHEAsACgZSYM3Zc%2BAkRIBcUKAGIoAMUoBnQlDL4QAVxQwsDKACML%2BJpZPBcsRCYDGAC0LeANaEIIYyWlq6wijGeFDeuETe%2BIZIaChmFkThEQAmhAowZIaBABTuYJqGMCCM9mQgmqgwAJRQALQAfFDAFGBm6jkREQB0YzKEFMaD0sO6AIIocDC%2BqBj%2BRJiGUChg%2BH4BwblDsMVlbTpQomCedFAh4KGMJIQoUADu-m8WxrkfSCswE5MNhcDZ0CMoAAlKw2CAmJDbMhQXLyYAhV4pGC4OAjE4nUCQTAoYhgYIjIolbZYHBxSmBGQyIikSg0LylekXXSlaq1YmtDrdXr9GAyIA) [`TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING).

Comment: Note that the signature(s) you cast to depends entirely on how you want it to be. These methods allow you to reapply type hints on anything not written by you. (Sorry for splitting into three comments, the playground links are too long.)

Comment: OK, so then there is no way to do this on import- ie even if I do explicitly cast it myself, my type checker will still complain right? In your own example its still showing that warning. I guess I had two questions, how to remove the ambiguity in my own code without modifying the package AND if there is a way to remove the warning on the import statement (again without ignoring it entirely there).

Comment: @red888 There is: Put it in the `else` branch of the `TYPE_CHECKING` guard and define your own signature in the `if` branch, as demonstrated in the second playground I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `task` is partially unknown because the special hint `Any` doesn't provide any actual information. It's the type that would have inferred for

```
def task(*args, **kwargs) -> Callable:
```

So the only thing you really know is that `task` returns a callable of some kind.

Without or without the annotation, the function is not type-safe. `Any` essentially *turns off* type-checking for the values involved. For example, the following will type-check:

```
task(klass="foo")
```

That's because `kwargs['klass'] = "foo"` works, because `kwargs['klass']` also has the type `Any`, and a `str` value is compatible with `Any`. Further, a value of type `Any` is compatible with `Type[Task]`, so

```
klass: Type[Task] = "foo"
```

is valid.

So yes, there is quite a bit wrong with the definition of `task` as far as type-checking goes. It's not that easy to fix, though, because of its very dynamic nature. Something like

```
P = ParamSpec('P')
RV = TypeVar('RV')

def task(*args: P.args, *klass: Type[Task] = Task, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> Callable[P, RV]:
    ...
```

might go a long way towards fixing it, but I haven't tested this. The idea is to say "we don't know what types `args` and `kwargs` can take, but whatever gets passed as runtime will fix what kind of callable can actually be returned. Something more complicated involving the actual types that can be passed to `Task` would probably be better.